# How can i render 2 documents per row from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a collection in `Firebase` called cvModels contains many documents ,
What I want to achieve is to show 2 documents per each row (all the documents).

Each document has 2 fields:

- **img**: which is a link to an image
- **name**: which is a String

Everything will be rendered in a `ListView` or a `GridView`.

So far I have this `Function`, that only expands the whole row for only 1 document.

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("cvModels").snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext  context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return new ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
          return new Row(
            // textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: 40,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(ds["img"].toString()),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Expanded (
              //   child: Container(
              //     height: 100,
              //     width: 100,
              //     child:Text(ds["name"]),
              //   ),
              // ),
              // Expanded (child:Text(ds["last-field"].toString()) ),
            ],
          );
        }  
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Any help would be appreciated , Thanks .

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with your code. What error are you getting?

Comment: @JoãoSoares i said the code is working well , but what i want is a diffrent thing .
I wanna show 2 items per each row , not 1/row .

Comment: By the looks of your commented code, you had already implemented it. Is the text not showing? You already have a row with two elements inside. Is there a screenshot you can show us that would help understand what you have and what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @JoãoSoares thats  still just image and name of 1 document .
I meant is to actually show 2 documents in 1 row means (doc1> img + name) + (doc2 > img + name)  both in 1 row .

Comment: The loop in the ListView.builder goes through your list of documents one by one. On the first run you are on item 0 of your list, but you want to show item 0 and item 1. On the second run you are on item 1, but now you want to display item 2 and 3. Do you see the problem? Wouldn't a GridView widget be a better solution for you?

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes that's exactly the problem , i tried to play with the index and add one to it but it just not too perfect , as for the GridView.builder   could you please show / demonstrate and example on how to async that with my documentSnapshots  down bellow  ?
im kind of new to that feature .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, try replacing your `ListView.builder` with a `GridView.builder`:

```
return GridView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Row(
      // textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: 120,
            width: 40,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black12,
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(ds["img"].toString()),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded (
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child:Text(ds["name"]),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded (child:Text(ds["last-field"].toString())),
      ],
    );
  },
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2
  ),
)
```

Comment: It works fine ,  can u edit and add 
DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];

under the itemBuilder  , just for next/ future users that might have same problem.

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Shooting from the hip here since I can't see visually what you're after but can't you do this to fetch the current snapshot as well as the next one:

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index];
DocumentSnapshot nextSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index + 1];
```

And in your `Row` simply add the widgets that will display the info for both snapshots? Perhaps wrapping your `Expanded` widgets in its own `Widget` (`RowInfo` as an example) to make it cleaner so that your final `Row` would look something like:

```
Row(
  children: [
    RowInfo(img: snapshot['img'], name: snapshot['name']),
    RowInfo(img: nextSnapshot['img'], name: nextSnapshot['name'])
  ]
)
```

**EDIT:** To check if `nextSnapshot` exists you can simply wrap it in an `if` and return either two `RowInfo` or one:

```
if (nextSnapshot == null) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      RowInfo(img: snapshot['img'], name: snapshot['name'])
    ]
  )
}
else {
  return Row(
    children: [
      RowInfo(img: snapshot['img'], name: snapshot['name']),
      RowInfo(img: nextSnapshot['img'], name: nextSnapshot['name'])
    ]
  )
}
```

Comment: Actually I realy haven't though of it , i'm gonna try a little piece of that , however it should check if the index +1 exists or catch the exception ..etc

Comment: @DeckerTammy Added a snippet on how to do that.

Comment: I just Tried it , it works fine , Thanks a lot @Chrillewoodz :D